# Returning id from node.js is not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js

EDIT: The problem is that the console.log(theID) executes before the value is assigned in the query callback. So my problem now is how to have the query callback to run first so that theID is assigned to a value before I return it

Here is the Server.js.

```
app.get('/testtwilio2', function(req,res,next){
    var theID;
    var p;
    var config;
     var pat = {name: req.query.name, number: req.query.number, date:req.query.date, reminded: 0, paid:0 };
        connection.query('INSERT INTO patientlist SET ?', pat, function(err,res){

        if(err) throw err;
             theID = res.insertId

            console.log('Last insert ID:', theID); //returns correct value
             p = {id: theID, name: req.query.name, date: req.query.date, number: req.query.number, reminded: req.query.reminded};
        var fs = require('fs');
        var configFile = fs.readFileSync('./Public/worked.json');
        var config = JSON.parse(configFile);

        var object = req.query.name;
        config.push(p);
        var configJSON = JSON.stringify(config);
        fs.writeFileSync('./Public/worked.json', configJSON);


        });
        console.log(theID); //this executes first meaning theID hasn't been assigned a value
        return res.json(theID);
});
```

Comment: Debugging API with Angular isn't the most efficient way of doing it. There are dev tools and network tab. If `theID` is logged correctly on server side, it doesn't have anything to do with MySQL, it is just Express question. If it does not, it is purely MySQL question. If server responds correctly, it is purely Angular question.

Comment: I found why it isn't working but not sure how to go about fixing it. I edited the post to explain the problem

Comment: You need to put `res.json(theID)` inside callback and not return it. `res` and its methods were made as functions exactly to make async responses possible.

Comment: When I do that, I get an error stating that "res.json is not a function"

Comment: Sure, `res` param is shadowed in query callback. Name one of them differently.

Comment: whoops. Got it to work, thanks for the help